# ckeditor - automatically remove all attributes of selected tags

Tags: ckeditor

Is there any setting for CKEditor to remove all attributes from defined tags. For example I'll define these tags `"h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6"` and editor will remove all attributes from these tags automatically without pressing any button.

I've found this [removeFormatTags](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-removeFormatTags) but it only runs if you click remove format. Is there any setting will do this automatically?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using CKEditor 4.1+ you can do exactly this with the [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter). With it you can define which elements can have which attributes and which styles even.